# Change for {if} statemets to try...catch

Tags: java

I am stuck in these lines of code and don't know how to change it. My professor asked me to do this, saying, "Do not use `instanceof`, or `break`, except inside of switch statements." I am trying to change it to `try...catch` statements. I keep getting stuck. Any help? This is my code:

```
   public void displayAllTreasures() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.button.length; i++) 

    {     //This is what i am trying to change to try/catch
        if (this.button[i] instanceof TreasureButton)

            this.button[i].setText(this.button[i].getDisplayText());
    }
}
```

Comment: `My proffesor asked me to do this "Do not use instanceof, or break, except inside of switch statements."` Either you interpret your prof. requirement wrong or he's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a type cast. If `instanceof` were to return `false`, then the try/catch will cause a class cast exception:

```
try {
    TreasureButton buttonI = (TreasureButton) this.button[i];
    buttonI.setText(this.button[i].getDisplayText());
} catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    //do else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use `instanceof` if you don't know the precise type of the `button` array, in which case - you use `instanceof` to check if it's safe to cast. Since you don't cast, I don't see why you have `instanceof` here at all. But assuming you ***meant*** to cast; then you could do so blindly in `try-catch` and catch a `ClassCastException` if it isn't legal. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.button.length; i++) {
    try {
        TreasureButton tb = (TreasureButton) this.button[i];
        tb.setText(tb.getDisplayText());
    } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    }
}
```